# Embedding schemas is giving error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

I am trying to embed schemas in other schemas that I have created, and I keep getting this error:

I am not entirely sure what is going wrong here, but what I want to do is store references to my event schema and interests schema inside the user schema.  If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great thanks!

**EDIT: I am now receiving a new error:**

```
   /Users/Dynee/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:421
  throw new TypeError('Invalid value for schema Array path `' + prefix + key + '`');
  ^

TypeError: Invalid value for schema Array path `eventsHosted`
at Schema.add (/Users/Dynee/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:421:13)
at new Schema (/Users/Dynee/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:99:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Dynee/Documents/eventure-rest-backend/Models/User.js:5:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Dynee/Documents/eventure-rest-backend/Models/Event.js:2:43)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

**My User Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var EventSchema = require('../Models/Event').schema;
var InterestSchema = require('../Models/Interest').schema;

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    eventsHosted: [EventSchema],
    eventsAttended: [EventSchema],
    currentlyAttending: [EventSchema],
    currentlyHosting: [EventSchema],
    profileImage: String,
    interests: [InterestSchema],
    followers: [UserSchema],
    following: [UserSchema]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**My Event Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var UserSchema = require('../Models/User').schema;

var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    location: String,
    attendees: [UserSchema],
    date: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

**My Interests Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var InterestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Interest', InterestSchema);
```

Comment: I looked at that thread and it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's because what you are exporting in your modules aren't `Schemas`, they are `Models`. When you do `var EventSchema = require('../Models/Event');` you are requiring the `Event Model`, not the `Event Schema`. To access the underlying schemas from your models you can do:

```
var EventSchema = require('../Models/Event').schema;
var InterestSchema = require('../Models/Interest').schema;
var UserSchema = require('../Models/User').schema;
```

You also have a problem when you are referencing documents that belongs to another collection, this should work:

**Event Model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var UserSchema = require('./User').schema;

var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    location: String,
    attendees: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    date: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

**Interest Model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var InterestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Interest', InterestSchema);
```

**User Model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var EventSchema = require('./Event').schema;
var InterestSchema = require('./Interest').schema;

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    eventsHosted: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event' }],
    eventsAttended: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event' }],
    currentlyAttending: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event' }],
    currentlyHosting: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event' }],
    profileImage: String,
    interests: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Interest' }],
    followers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    following: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

[How to reference another schema in my Mongoose schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078753/how-to-reference-another-schema-in-my-mongoose-schema)
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Hello! thank you for replying, I added the .schema to the end of each of my imports however, I am getting a similar error edited my post with the new error, if you could take a look and see what I might be doing wrong I would appreciate it.

Comment: What if I want to reference the whole Event, User, or Interest?  The eventsHosted, attended ect.. I want to have reference the whole object and not be just a Number. Perhaps I could just do Schema.Types.ObjectId instead and then I could access the whole Event, User, or Interest that I want it to reference?

Comment: It's fixed now ;)

Comment: Okay I think I understand now, so when I am querying for events that are currently attended, I can just access them by the id because it is a reference to the Event?  Thank you very much for your help I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, if you want to have the documents instead of the original _ids, just call `populate`, this page has a really good example of this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Great answer! Saved me lots of time!

Comment: how to do this in ts?