# Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `characters`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a schema subdocument but am getting the error listed above, 
The schemas in question look like this 
**Schema casuing issues**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const CharacterSchema = new Schema();
CharacterSchema.add({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    charcterClass: { // will be limited in form creation
        type: String
    },
    level: {
        type: Number
    }
});

const Charcter = mongoose.model('User', CharacterSchema);
module.exports = Charcter;
```

**Schema calling schema above**

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const {CharacterSchema} = require(__dirname +'/CharacterModel.js');

const UserSchema = new Schema()
UserSchema.add({
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    } ,
    characters: [CharacterSchema]
});

const User = mongoose.model('Character', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Export the Schema as a Schema.  Not a mongoose model.  module.exports = CharacterSchema;

Answer (score 18):

Try to do the import like this way
 `const {CharacterSchema} = require(__dirname +'/CharacterModel.js').schema;`

Adding the `.schema` at the end.

This post is related to your issue, you will see the explanation there.

[Embedding schemas is giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024285/embedding-schemas-is-giving-error/43024503)

Answer (score 3):

UserSchema :

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CharacterSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    charcterClass: { 
        type: String
    },
    level: {
        type: Number
    }
});

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    } ,
    characters:{ 
        type:[CharacterSchema]
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Comment: That's really emberrising, although when fixing the model name it's still throwing an error      Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `characters`

Comment: is your characters model is used in other place or just in user model ?

Comment: The error is generating from The schema, however I do use it in my app.js in a post route that looks like this
`
User.find({'name': req.params.user})
    .then(results => {
        const UserToPush = new User(results);
        console.log(UserToPush);
        UserToPush.characters.push(newCharacter);
        UserToPush.save();
        res.status(201).send(newCharacter);
        
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.error(err);
    })
`

Comment: well that fixes it but then how would I create a character? or access a characterSchema if they are in the same file

Comment: characters are stored in User schema

Comment: how do you set a default value to the type: [CharacterSchema] ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are importing the Character model because `module.exports = Charcter;` is a default export like `export default Character` and when you say `const {CharacterSchema} = require(__dirname +'/CharacterModel.js');` you basically refer this `Character` model as `CharacterSchema` - once again - because of the default export.

So the solution is:

```js
module.exports = Character; // Default export
module.exports.CharacterSchema = CharacterSchema; // Named export

// ...

const CharacterModel = require('./CharacterModel.js'); // Import the default export (Character model)
const { CharacterSchema } = require('./CharacterModel.js'); // Import the named export (CharacterSchema )
```

and you need to use it like you originally did: `characters: [CharacterSchema]`

This issue is reproducable when you use `import ... from ...` - ES6 module syntax.