# Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

EDIT: My code here is correct, as is the answer I received. I realized after posting and getting an answer that the error was coming from another file not posted here. I'm posting this edit because I don't want to delete.

I'm quite sure I'm importing a schema, but for some reason it's being interpreted as a Model and I'm getting this Invalid Schema Configuration error. Here's the schema that's getting imported:

user.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    //eventsUpdated: [Schema.ObjectId],   // ids of events updated
    //flags: [Schema.ObjectId],   // ids of flags of events
});

const user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = user;
```

And here's the file that's importing:
flag.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = require('./user').schema;

const flagSchema = new Schema({
    field: String,
    count: Number,
    IPs: [String],
    lastCleared: Date,
    clearedBy: [userSchema]
});

const flag = mongoose.model('flag', flagSchema);

module.exports = flag;
```

I've tried importing different ways, like explicitly exporting only the userSchema in user.js, and nothing has solved it or even given a different error. I've tried solutions offered by similar questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59131840/invalid-schema-configuration-model-is-not-a-valid-type-within-the-array-char). Please help, and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you are not exporting userSchema

instead of

```
module.exports = user;
```

use

```
module.exports = {
  user,
  userSchema
};
```

and then require it

```
const { userSchema } = require('./user');
```

Comment: But I am importing the schema with this line, correct? ```const userSchema = require('./user').schema;```  Also, I tried your suggestion, it's giving me the same error.

Comment: yes you are correct.
and this is an example you can check it out 
maybe it would help
https://repl.it/repls/OffshoreCluelessCommand